# Javascript debugging in qt webkit

Tags: javascript, debugging, qtwebkit, inspector, qtwebview

I'm trying to debug java-script with qt web-kit, but it's not working.

I right click on qt web-view and choose "Inspect", in inspector window, I go to "Scripts" tab, I choose "Only enable for this session / Always enable" then press "Enable Debugging" button.

In the JavaScript file, I place a break point in the function (by clicking on line number). I can see the line in "Breakpoints" group in right side of window as well. I perform a specific action which causes function's launch (in UI), but nothing happens, the break point does not hit and the function returns.

If I invoke the function manually from the console by typing its name and arguments, still nothing happens. The function returns without hitting the break point.

I also enabled `JavascriptEnabled`.

I'm using Qt 4.8 and Visual Studio 2008.

What's wrong here?